# Python Помогите пожалуйста с тэгом <a> с Xpath оси путей

Tags: python, xml, парсер, selenium, xpath

Python selenium. источник парсинга [tgstat.ru](https://tgstat.ru)
Конкретно с осями путей xpath
как спарсить все в списке тэг <а>, точнее имена которые вылазят, нужна ссылка.
Есть такой вариант

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]
```

но он не прокатит, не валидный и плохо так писать `div[1]div[2]` и т.д
мне надо например `".//div[@class=a???????]"`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык, иначе не понятно, чего Вы хотите. Что значит `все в списке тэг <а>`? `точнее имена которые вылазят` - какие имена? Откуда "вылазят"? У меня ничего не "вылазит".

Comment: Попробуй `find_elements_by_css_selector(".row > div > a")`

Comment: попробовал, куча пробелов вылезло `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7d9ef524-3360-4d22-8939-9322667dbe0b", element="2ed6c7b9-abd2-484f-bd38-336fe54ec93a")>`

Comment: я с .text  пробовал то были пробелы

Comment: по идеи с тэга <a> мне нужна ссылка

Comment: Так ты не данные этим методом получаешь, а список элементов. Потом нужно циклом по ним пройти и вынуть текст.

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял какие конкретно ссылки вам нужны, но как то так

```
/html/body//div/a/@href
```

или так

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/@href
```

и вариант три текст из ссылок или ключи как будет угодно

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/text()
```

Сам код чтоб проще понять было

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://tgstat.ru/')
sleep(2)
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a')

# Вытащит текст ссылок
# a = [ii.text for ii in element]
# print(a)

# Ссылки
a = [ii.get_attribute('href') for ii in element]
print(a)
```